# Android Navigation Component - How to "popBackStack" to non-existing Destination

Tags: android, navigation, back-stack

Default route in my app is - `Auth -> Main -> Chat`. But sometimes I need to use another route: `Auth -> Details -> Chat`. When I press back button (in both cases) I want to navigate to the `Main` screen, but it's not in the backstack in the second case. I tried to create [Global-action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) to navigate from the `Details` screen to `Chat` with a `popUpTo == Main`:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_global_to_chat"
    app:destination="@id/navigation_chat"
    app:launchSingleTop="true"
    app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_main_host" />
```

But it doesn't work because `navigation_main_host` is not in the backstack. Is there any way to get this behavior?

**UPD:** I tried another solution - I created another action in my `Chat` destination with a `popup inclusive` behavior:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_chat_to_main_host"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_main_host"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_auth"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Then I tried to use it in my `ChatFragment`:

```
private val backPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        if (activityController?.getNavController()?.previousBackStackEntry?.destination?.id == R.id.navigation_main_host) {
            activityController?.getNavController()?.popBackStack()
        } else {
            activityController?.getNavController()?.navigate(ChatDirections.actionChatToMainHost())
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try it I got this route:

`Auth -> Details -> Chat`

then I start pressing back button:

`Chat -> Main -> Chat -> Main -> Chat -> Main....` in the unlimited cycle.

`backPressedCallback` is enabled in `onResume` and disabled in `onPause` to make it clear.

Comment: Check this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link

Comment: @Abhimanyu what exactly you wanted to show me on this page? I've read it but there's no answer for my question.

Comment: I assume this is your use case. Please let me know if I am missing anything.
You want your app to handle an intent to open a specific screen (Chat screen). When a user presses the Back button, they navigate back up the navigation stack just as though they entered your app from its entry point.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I edited my question and removed the confusing part. Please take a look.

Comment: To confirm, once you are on the "Chat" screen, on back press should always navigate to the "Main" screen?

Comment: @Abhimanyu yes, exactly.

Comment: You can override back press functionality in the chat screen and navigate to the main screen as you required. Any issues with that?

Comment: @Abhimanyu edited my question again, already tried it.

Comment: Just need a bit more clarity. In route 1 `Auth -> Main -> Chat` on back press of chat should navigate to main. On back press of main - should it navigate to auth or close the app? Similarly in route 2 `Auth -> Details -> Chat`  on back press of chat should navigate to main. What is the expectation of on back press of main?

Comment: Back press of main should always close the app. I tried to create BackPressedDispatcher in MainFragment, call activity.finish() inside of it and it works, but I don't like this solution - it looks like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223410/discussion-between-abhimanyu-and-den).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use-case. Sharing my implementation. Hope it works for you.

**In MainActivity:**

```
// Navigation component global variables
private lateinit var navController: NavController
private lateinit var navGraph: NavGraph

// In onCreate()
// fragment_activitymain is a <fragment>
navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment_activitymain)
navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.navigation)

private fun setStartDestination(startDestination: Int) {
    navGraph.startDestination = startDestination
    navController.graph = navGraph
}
```

To call the method setStartDestination():

```
setStartDestination(R.id.MainFragmentIdInNavigationGraph)
```

The method `setStartDestination()` in the activity can be called from any fragment by using an interface or `livedata`  with a `shared ViewModel` or any other way in which fragment to activity communication is implemented in your app.

To get the required flow, override on back presses in "Chat" and use an action to navigate from "Chat" to "Main" rather than popping up destinations from the backstack. Setting "Main" as the start destination clear the destinations below main.

The flow works like this,
Route 1:
Auth -> Main -> Chat -> Use action to navigate to main & set it as start method to clear the "Chat" and "Main" from the backstack. "Auth" won't be in the backstack as you are using popUp in Auth to Main action.

Route 2:
Auth -> Details -> Chat -> Use action to navigate to main & set it as start method to clear the "Chat" and "Details" from the backstack. "Auth" won't be in the backstack if you are using popUp in Auth to Details action, else it would be in the backstack which will also be cleared when we change start destination.

Answer (score 0):

Bit hacky, but you could try:

```
private val backPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        if (activityController?.getNavController()?.previousBackStackEntry?.destination?.id == R.id.navigation_main_host) {
            activityController?.getNavController()?.popBackStack()
        } else {
            activityController?.getNavController()?.popBackStack(R.id.navigation_auth, true)
            activityController?.getNavController()?.navigate(ChatDirections.actionChatToMainHost())
        }
    }
}
```

Change the `R.id.navigation_auth` to the id of your `Auth`.

This would lead to:

`Auth -> Details -> Chat` backing up to
`Auth -> Main`